# blink a wpf datagrid row

Tags: wpf, datagrid, row, blink

I am new to WPF. I have a requirement where I need to blink a data grid row If the value in the Date is column is less than current date. My Grid is like below.

**Name Date**

Test     12-02-2015.

Please help me with a complete example solution.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, this is not a code writing service. Show us what you have tried and what's wrong with your solution, then we can give specific answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do first of all is to read about:

1. [MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level)
2. [Styles](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18388/A-Guided-Tour-of-WPF-Part-Styles)
3. [Triggers](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/522041/Triggers-in-WPF)
4. [ValueConverters](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)

Ofcourse, you have to read msdn's articles about WPF.

Try to write something, and if something goes wrong, discribe your problems on Stack Overflow and we will help you. Have a nice coding!